# Stuck on Simple PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ive been toying with this for the last half hour and cannot figure out with the life of me what is wrong.

Ever since I've added this to my PHP document I am getting a blank page. Note, it fails on the PDO. I am not new to PDO by any means, but for some reason this failing is stumping me. All the data correlates in the database.

The page is returning blank, no errors in error log.

```
$value = "9EED4A5E4A54DC41195C8949C87ABA5FD6C035CD795188E179F9EF76FC7154FF";

if (!empty($_COOKIE['hash'])){
    $dbuser = "user";
    $dbpass = "pass";
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE hash = :hash');
    $stmt->bindParam(':hash', $value);
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $stmt->fetchColumn();

}
```

Note the cookie is being set in a previous page. The if statement works, just not the pro

Comment: The page doesn't display anything ... seems like it's supposed to be blank

Comment: Yeah there's no `echo` or `print` or anything :)  Try a `var_dump` on the result, or maybe something's up in your `php.ini` that's hiding errors.  Use `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to show everything (not for release version though!)  It could be working correctly though.

Comment: the page isn't blank. theres html and the php dies.

Comment: @Ray why do you think you don't need to use `execute` if you use `fetchColumn`?

Comment: i didn't include the html as it is not the issue, I've narrowed it down to this code

Comment: still not working with execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query` executes a query immediately.  The method you want to use is `prepare`.  You also need to call `execute` after the parameters are bound.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":hash", $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

In case PDO is failing you should probably also turn error reporting on for it.

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: I only want to fetch a single result column in a row

Comment: @Ray See the documentation for [`fetchColumn`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) -- they use `execute` first in their examples.

Comment: Completely looked over the fact that I was using query. Thanks